# how to change the size of groups for ab testing?

Tags: civimail, abtesting

I've started a test with a sample too small to be statistically significant. I would like to re-run the test but with a bigger one.

however, I would want to exclude those that already participated to the initial a or b test. when I clone, I can exclude from previous mailings, but only from the final, not from the a or b tests. is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so what I did was to search the contacts in the original a and b groups, and added them into a new group already-tested, that I then excluded this group from the cloned ab testing.

note that i had to copy paste in the new ab-test, as the re-use feature doesn't properly clone the ab experiment, just one of the version